# How to setCenter for polylines and polygons?‏

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm using this code to center my points in the `map` screen:

```
var centerPoint = new OpenLayers.LonLat(feature.geometry.x, feature.geometry.y);
map.setCenter(centerPoint);
```

What should I use to center polylines and polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

```
var ft = vectorLayer.features[0];
var bounds = ft.geometry.bounds;
if(zoom)
    map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
else
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenterLonLat());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
map.setCenter(map.layers[1].getDataExtent().getCenterLonLat(),12);
```

This will center your map to the center of your vector layer 1, at a zoom level 12.

Comment: thanks for the the idea, how about if I want to set the zoom according to the size of each feature? I mean I have a big polygon and a point with the same name, both features are selected but they are not zoomed proportionally to their sizes, is it possible?

Comment: found the solution, it was just to use ft.geometry.id and if/else with a like operator